# have only one class name append to the end of href of an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, anchor

```
var myClass;

jQuery(".option-set a").click(function() {
myClass = jQuery(this).attr("class");

jQuery("a.perma").each(function() {
    var _href = jQuery(this).attr("href"); 
    jQuery(this).attr("href", _href + "#filter=." + myClass);
});
});
```

Im using this code to append the class name of the filters  to the end of the permalink for each thumbnail [here](http://427design.com/newsite/our-work/)

The issue Im running into now is that the class keeps getting assigned to the end of the permalink with each click so if I click on print then web then photography the url of the permalink would appear as: /#filter=.print#filter=.web#filter=.photography which still works, however it would be great if for the sake of tidiness it only displayed the last one.

Also once a thumbnail is clicked and the next page is loaded, I need the thumbnails to maintain the current permalink of the filter selected. Any ideas would be appreciated. I just cant seem to figure this out. I truly appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modification should check if current class filter is not present.

```
jQuery("a.perma").each(function() {
  var _href = jQuery(this).attr("href"),
      newHref = _href.indexOf(myClass) === -1 ? _href + "#filter=." + myClass : _href;
    jQuery(this).attr("href", newHref);
  });
});
```

And to maintain filtered thumbnail urls on next page load you need to work with server and parse what parameters it passes or use [Web storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) to save current filtered path and set thumbnail hrefs accordingly on document load.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! it worked perfectly. Ill look into Web storage.

Answer (score 1):

call it just once not on every click...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    myClass = jQuery('.option-set a').attr("class");

    jQuery("a.perma").each(function() {
        var _href = jQuery(this).attr("href"); 
        jQuery(this).attr("href", _href + "#filter=." + myClass);
    });

    jQuery(".option-set a").click(function() {...});
});
```